# Homeomorphism between cylinder and one-sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: general-topology, continuity, surfaces

Let $C = \left\{x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\right\}$ be a infinite cone, $H = \left\{x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^{2} + y^{2} - z^{2}= 1\right\}$ one sheeted hyperboloid. Using cylindrical coordinates
\begin{gather}
C = \left\{\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}\cos(\varphi),\sqrt{1+z^2}\sin(\varphi),z\right)\mid z\in\mathbb{R},\varphi\in[0,2\pi]\right\},\\
H = \left\{\left(\cos(\varphi),\sin(\varphi),z\right)\mid z\in\mathbb{R},\varphi\in[0,2\pi]\right\}. 
\end{gather}
So i suspect that the mapping
\begin{equation}
\eta: \left(\sqrt{1+z^2}\cos(\varphi),\sqrt{1+z^2}\sin(\varphi),z\right) \to  \left(\cos(\varphi),\sin(\varphi),z\right)
\end{equation}
is a homeomorphism (moreover a diffeomorphism?) of C and H, however I don’t quite understand how to show that it is a homeomorphysm by definition. Is it enough to show that $\eta$ and $\eta^{-1}$ are continuous componentwise? (The fact that $\eta$ is one to one is obvious).

Does the homeomorphism of $C$ and $H$ entails that $H$ is connected and not compact?

Comment: Yes, after defining $\eta$ and $\eta^{-1}$ properly (for each of them, before your $\mapsto$ sign, there must be a mere triple $(x,y,z)$, not functions like $\sqrt{1+z^2}\cos\varphi$), you just have to show they are continous, i.e. each component is. You can even show they are differentiable (hence $H$ and $C$ are diffeomorphic). And yes, homeomorphisms preserve connectedness and compacity.

Comment: @anne-bauval, thanks!